# Can a function ever cross a vertical asymptote?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-functions

I have the function $f(x) = \frac {x^2-1}{x^2-4}$ that I need to graph.

This is what I found:

Vertical asymptotes: $x=2$ and $x=-2$

Horizontal asymptote: $y = 1$

$x$-intercepts: $x = 1$ and $x = -1$

$y$-intercept: $y = \frac 14$

Then I wanted to see if the function would ever cross the horizontal asymptote so I set the function equal to the asymptote and solved $1=\frac {x^2-1}{x^2-4}$ and I found that it doesn't cross the horizontal asymptote.

Then I set the function equal to the vertical asymptote and solved for $x$ so 
$2 = \frac {x^2-1}{x^2-4}$ and I got $x = -\sqrt 7$ and $x = +\sqrt 7$

I thought a line could never cross the vertical asymptotes so what are these values I got and how do I graph them?

Comment: You found the points where the $y$ coordinate equals 2, not the $x$ coordinate. $x=2$ is not part of the domain, so the function cannot cross it, as it is not defined there.

Comment: then how come when i set 2 equal to the equation i got values ? what do does two  x = -√7 and x = +√7 mean ?

Comment: Read over dafinguzman's post carefully. You set $y=2$ and found what $x$ values can give you that value. You did not set $x=2$, which is where the vertical asymptote lies. The fact is, you can't set $x=\pm2$, since that would result in a divide by zero error.

Comment: Those are the points in the horizontal axis where the function achieves the value of 2 in the vertical axis. Those points are located in the coordinates $\pm \sqrt 7$ of the horizontal axis; They are not points in the asymptotes, which are positioned in the points 2 and -2 of the horizontal axis.

Comment: thanks it makes sense now.